# Calculation of an inverse Mellin transform

Tags: integral-transforms, integral-operators, integral-kernel

Let $z \in C$ and consider the following integral equation:
$$-\frac{\Gamma(a)}{\Gamma(b)}\frac{1}{ z \dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z} {_{1}F_{1}}(b,b-a;z)}= \int_{0}^{+ \infty}x^{z-1}K(x) \mathrm{d}x$$
I would like to find the kernel $K(x)$ and I would also like to write it as an infinite product: have tried to search on many books but I didn't find the desired result (I looked especially in the books "*Tables of integral transforms*" and "*Tables of Mellin transforms*").
Thank you and best regards.

Comment: $ _{1}F_{1}(b,b-a;z)$ is the hypergeometric function

Answer (score 4):

Because of the identity
$$\frac{d}{dz}\, _1F_1(b;b-a;z)=\frac{b }{b-a}\, _1F_1(b+1;b+1-a;z)$$
the function $K(x)$ is given by
$$K(x)=-\frac{(b-a)\Gamma(a)}{b\Gamma(b)}f(a,b,x)$$
with $f(a,b,x)$ the inverse Mellin transform of $\frac{1}{z\;_1F_1(b+1,b+1-a;z)}$.

For integer $a$ this has a closed form expression as a power series in $x$, for example,
$$f(1,b,x)=\theta(1-e|x|)(1-(ex)^b),\;\;b>0.$$

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: What is $\theta$ and e?

Comment: $\theta(x)$ is the unit step function (equal to unity if $x>0$, equal to zero otherwise), $e$ is the base of the natural logarithm.

Comment: Is $f(a,b,x)$ equal to $\theta(a−e|x|)(a−(ex)^{b})$?

Comment: And can we express the hypergeometric function as an infinite product?

Comment: no, for example, $f(2,4,x)=\frac{1}{2}\theta(1-e|x| )\bigl((e x)^6-3 (e x)^2+2\bigr)$.

Comment: What is exactly the value of $f(a,b,x)$ ?

Comment: these are exact results for specific values of $a,b$; there is no closed-form expression for unspecified $a,b$.